# Angular Bootstrap UI - Only collapsing one element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the angular bootstrap UI library:

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

to create a collapsable feature on my site. The functionality itself is working, but it will expand/collapse every element I have the collapse feature on, instead of just the unique element that is clicked.

Here is my code:

```js
var app = angular.module('someApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('collapseController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  
   $scope.isCollapsed = true;
};
```

```css
.passInfoDropdown {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dividerLine {
  background-color: #DED7CF;
  height: 2px;
}

.passInfoTableCellLeft {
  width: 220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dividerLine"></div>
<div class="click" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="passInfoTableCellLeft"><div class="passInfoDropdown inline">TSA Information (optional)</div></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-chevron-down inline"></i></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div collapse="isCollapsed">
    <div class="well well-lg">Some content</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dividerLine"></div>
<div class="click" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="passInfoTableCellLeft"><div class="passInfoDropdown inline">Loyalty Programs (optional)</div></td>
      <td><i class="fa fa-chevron-down inline"></i></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div collapse="isCollapsed">
    <div class="well well-lg">Some content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make it so just the unique element i click collapses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment both isCollapsed refer to the same propertie on your $scope object. If you want those to be separed, I see two options.

1. Two properties in the scope

   ```
   $scope.isCollapsedContent1 = true;
   $scope.isCollapsedContent2 = true;
   ```

   or

   ```
   $scope.isCollapsed = {};
   $scope.isCollapsed['content1'] = true;
   $scope.isCollapsed['content2'] = true;
   ```
2. Two ng-model

If you do not need to know whether the content is collapsed or not in your controller, you might as well put the isCollapsed value into your html and remove the propertie of your $scope.

```
    <div class="click" ng-click="isCollapsedContent1 = !isCollapsedContent1" ng-model="isCollapsedContent1" ng-init="isCollapsedContent1=true">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Brandon**, HI there. It also looks (in the full snippet code) like you have left out these....
`<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">`
and
`<div ng-controller="CollapseDemoCtrl">`

Have a look at the working **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bshp9Lxd/)**.